# How to iterate or find all the wanted occurrences in an XML file and replace the them?

Tags: python, regex, xml, entity

I've tried many ways, but don't seem to be progressing that much. I wanted to change the `<` and `>` between `<p>` tags to be entities, but there are line breaks in between the content between

tags:
Example:

```
<html>
  <li>This is a test file.</li>
  <p>This is the sentence I want to <a
  href="XXXX.com">do</a> the entity conversion.</p>
  <p>This is a second <li>sentence</li>.</p>
</html>
```

Expected result is:

```
<html>
  <li>This is a test file.</li>
  <p>This is the sentence I want to &lt;a
  href="XXXX.com"&gt;do&lt;/a&gt; the entity conversion.</p>
  <p>This is a second &lt;li&gt;sentence&lt;/li&gt;.</p>
</html>
```

I can't seem to find the all the `<` and `>` to do the conversion.

If I try the Regex `<seg.*(<)`, it can't find all the `<`;
 if I try to use positive lookbehind like `<(?=.*<\/p>)(?!p>)`, it can't find all `<` when there's a line break inside the `<p>` content.
If I try to use positive lookbehind + re.DOTALL `<(?=.*<\/p>)(?!p>)`, it'll find all the `<`including those unwanted ones...

If you have any ideas on a better Regex or a better way of doing this, please let me know. Thank you very much!

Comment: You'll have some trouble with writing the regexes that span lines (at least I have).  My first step would be to strip all \n (perhaps replace with a 'holder' character) do your regexes which will be much easier now, then replace the holder back with \n

Answer (score 1):

With [**`xml.dom`**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.dom.html?highlight=dom) module:

```
from xml.dom import minidom

doc = minidom.parse("yourfile")
for p in doc.getElementsByTagName('p'):
    text_node = doc.createTextNode(p.childNodes[1].toxml())
    p.replaceChild(text_node, p.childNodes[1])

print(doc.childNodes[0].toxml())
```

The output:

```
<html>
  <li>This is a test file.</li>
  <p>This is the sentence I want to &lt;a href=&quot;XXXX.com&quot;&gt;do&lt;/a&gt; the entity conversion.</p>
  <p>This is a second &lt;li&gt;sentence&lt;/li&gt;.</p>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks, @RomanPerekhrest! I'm getting the error of `xml.parsers.expat.ExpatError: mismatched tag: line 47, column 2` though after passing the file name to the parse method...

Comment: @Penny, `mismatched tag` means that your html contents is invalid. I've tested on the example from your question - worked fine

Comment: Thank you @RomanPerekhrest! I got it later! Another thing is I have declared the encoding to be "utf-16", like `# coding = utf-16`, but it still throws me the error of `Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file test.xml on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details`. I'm trying to figure this out now

Comment: The xml declared its encoding correctly too: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>`. Not sure why the xml can't be parsed..

Answer (score 0):

Also you can try with this:-

```
with open('old.txt', 'r') as f:
 d = f.readlines()
#open a temporary file
out = open('filesort.txt', 'w')
check1 = True
check2 = False
endFound = False
for line in d:
nl = line
if(check1 and (line.find("<p>")) != -1):
    if(line.find("</p>") != -1):
        endFound = True
    nl = nl.replace('<','&lt;')
    nl = nl.replace('>','&gt;')
    nl = nl.replace('&lt;p&gt;','<p>')
    if(endFound):
        nl = nl.replace('&lt;/p&gt;','</p>')
        check1 = True
        check2 = False
    else:
        check1 = False
        check2 = True
elif(check2):
    if(line.find("</p>") != -1):
        endFound = True
    nl = nl.replace('<','&lt;')
    nl = nl.replace('>','&gt;')
    nl = nl.replace('&lt;p&gt;','<p>')
    if(endFound):
        nl = nl.replace('&lt;/p&gt;','</p>')
        check1 = True
        check2 = False
    else:
        check1 = False
        check2 = True   
out.writelines(nl)
```